# PHP fwrite prints numbers to the file instead of the actual content that I want to write to it

Tags: php, fwrite

So I recently have been trying to create a PHP script that runs and makes another webpage... I am trying to use fwrite to write to files and create them. The files ARE created BUT, the data that is written to them is not the data I want. One always writes 0 and another writes the other number. I can't quite figure out why this is happening and have been trying to solve this issue for a few hours now. If anyone knows of any solution to this problem or why this might be happening so I can solve it myself, that'd be nice to have.

```
function fwrite_stream($fp, $string) {
    for ($written = 0; $written < strlen($string); $written += $fwrite) {
        $fwrite = fwrite($fp, substr($string, $written));
        if ($fwrite === false) {
            return $written;
        }
    }
    return $written;
}


$ff1 = fopen("index.php", "w");
fwrite_stream($ff1, $content);
fclose($ff1);
//I can provide $content if you believe that is the issue but I have it all unindented and its hard to read.
//I also have tried just using fwrite() and using fclose() the same result occurs.
```

This writes out...

> 53 (sometimes it writes a different number, but one thing that is always true is that it is a number)

Comment: Just curious, why not use `file_put_contents()`? Seems like it would be simpler.

Comment: If the file is not large than you should indeed use `file_put_contents()`

Comment: Incidentally, this code works just fine for me. Are you sure `$content` contains what you think it does when you pass it to that function?

Comment: Yeah that was the issue. The $content actually was wrong. I was using + to add two strings together instead of . so it was giving a number instead.